# What would be the reason for WinSCP using a ".com" instead of ".exe"?

Tags: windows, winscp

`winscp.com`. That's not a domain but an executable on Windows.

Why does it use the (I thought) ancient and MS-DOS-era `.com` executable instead of an `.exe`, like every other program in the last 30+ years?

Answer (score 7):

Despite the extension, it's actually a [PE file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) just like typical EXE files and not a COM file. Any extension that's listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable will be considered executable, and then when opening the file Windows or the registered application for that extension will check the signature to determine what type of executable it is (PE, NE, COM...) and execute accordingly. Try renaming any *.exe file to *.com or even *.cmd, *.bat and it'll still run normally

If you notice there's also *WinSCP.exe* in the same folder. The reason is because `WinSCP.exe` is the GUI and `WinSCP.com` is for running from command line

> WinSCP has two executables:
>
> - winscp.exe: Main executable, supports both GUI and console operation;
> - winscp.com: Console interface tool, supports console operation only, allows input/output redirection.
>
> [Executables winscp.exe and winscp.com](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables)

Windows apps [aren't allowed to be both a GUI and a console app at the same time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/?p=19643) so some tricks have to be used. By default COM is listed before EXE in `PATHEXT` so when you run a command without extension then the *.com file will be considered first. This is similar to the [devenv.com/devenv.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20040427000009/http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2004/02/06/68531.aspx) trick in Visual Studio, or soffice.com/soffice.exe in Libre Office. See [Can one executable be both a console and GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493536/995714)